# How to get input values to save to variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Kind of confused about how to capture values as an when they are saved to DB. This is laravel 5.4

In the app\Http\Controllers\Auth, I want to capture the input values that are being saved to the DB.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    Log::info('Adding the User ');  //  This is getting logged. 

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

     $name = $data['name'];

     Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$name);  //  This is not getting logged. 
}
```

The reason why I want to capture is because I want to send a curl request with the captured input data to a third party application as soon as a user is created.

Thank you.

Comment: you can not do this after your return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not executes any thing after your [returning](http://php.net/return) statement,

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function,

rather, you will need to store it in a variable then return it after doing your logging, something like follows :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    Log::info('Adding the User ');  //  This is getting logged. 

    $createdUser = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

     $name = $createdUser->name;

     Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$name);  //  This is not getting logged.

     return $createdUser;
}
```

---

### update

as long as you don't need a returned data from your DB, you may simple move this two lines :

```
$name = $data['name'];

Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$name);
```

before returning the creation object :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    Log::info('Adding the User ');  //  This is getting logged. 

    $name = $data['name'];

     Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$name);  //  This is not getting logged. 

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning created `User` instance do this:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

// Do stuff here
$name = $user->name;

return $user;
```